# Printing diagonal elements of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

l'm trying to print the diagonal numbers of  a square 2D array but l'm having a hard time with it.It's because of how l create the array isn't it? What l am doing wrong?

```
int[][] arr1 = { { 1, 2,6}, { 3, 4,5} }; // l'm stuck here

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j <arr1.length; j++) { 
            System.out.print(arr1[i][j] + " "); 
        } 

        System.out.println(); 
    }
     for (int k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
         System.out.println( arr1[k][k]);
     }
```

l expected to see 1    2    3
                  4    5    6
                  7    8    9
And for the actual results? l have being stuck

Comment: You have added two rows to your array, add the third one the same way.

Comment: If you have 3x3 matrix you will have 3 elements in one of the diagonals, not 9

Comment: @NiVeR the first print loop is just to verify the content of the array as I see it, the second loop is the attempt to solve the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array declaration should look like this:

```
int[][] arr1 = { { 1, 2, 3}, { 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
```

assuming you want an ordered 3 x 3 matrix.